# How to manage code comments using NetBeans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, netbeans, versioning, comments

I am using ruby on Rails 3 and my IDE is NetBeans v6.9.1.

Since in files I have a lot of comment lines that describe my code, and sometimes these comments are also repeated in multiple files, *there is a way to manage those in some way*? This should work as the feature "[auto-versioning](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=AutoVersioning)"... but also how you make these in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find you are repeating yourself in your comments, you are also likely repeating yourself in your code. Perhaps you should consider refactoring your code to make it more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Pull out common functionality, behavior, and data structures into central places so that you don't have the same code (and comments) in multiple locations.